# How to grep and output block of string separated by spaces from a single line output

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Is there a way to grep a single line of output with items separated by spaces and only output the exact block of string that begins and ends with spaces?

For instances, here is the output:

```
OK - Server: Supermicro Super Server s/n: 0123456789 System BIOS: 1.1 2015-04-09|P2Vol_0_Memory_Device_1_VDIMMAB=1.19;1.34;1.42 P2Vol_10_System_Board_19_3.3VSB=3.21;3.55;3.65 P2Vol_11_System_Board_20_1.5V_PCH=1.5;1.64;1.67 P2Vol_12_System_Board_21_1.2V_BMC=1.21;1.34;1.37 P2Vol_13_System_Board_32_3.3VCC=3.35;3.55;3.65 P2Vol_14_System_Board_33_5VCC=5;5.38;5.54 P2Vol_1_Memory_Device_2_VDIMMCD=1.19;1.34;1.42 P2Vol_2_Memory_Device_3_VDIMMEF=1.2;1.34;1.42 P2Vol_3_Memory_Device_4_VDIMMGH=1.19;1.34;1.42 P2Vol_4_Processor_3_Vcpu1=1.82;1.89;2.08 P2Vol_5_Processor_4_Vcpu2=1.82;1.89;2.08 P2Vol_6_System_Board_12_1.05V_PCH=1.05;1.19;1.22 P2Vol_7_System_Board_15_5VSB=5.07;5.38;5.54 P2Vol_8_System_Board_17_12V=12.18;12.94;13.25 P2Vol_9_System_Board_18_VBAT=2.87;3.67;3.78 P4Tem_0_Memory_Device_64_P1-DIMMA1_Temp=45;80;85 P4Tem_10_Processor_1_CPU1_Temp=47;80;85 P4Tem_11_Processor_2_CPU2_Temp=55;80;85 P4Tem_12_System_Board_1_System_Temp=32;80;85 P4Tem_13_System_Board_2_Peripheral_Temp=51;80;85 P4Tem_14_System_Board_3_PCH_Temp=44;90;95 P4Tem_1_Memory_Device_68_P1-DIMMB1_Temp=44;80;85 P4Tem_2_Memory_Device_80_P2-DIMME1_Temp=47;80;85 P4Tem_3_Memory_Device_84_P2-DIMMF1_Temp=45;80;85 P4Tem_4_Memory_Module_1_Vcpu1VRM_Temp=47;95;100 P4Tem_5_Memory_Module_2_Vcpu2VRM_Temp=54;95;100 P4Tem_6_Memory_Module_3_VmemABVRM_Temp=44;95;100 P4Tem_7_Memory_Module_4_VmemCDVRM_Temp=38;95;100 P4Tem_8_Memory_Module_5_VmemEFVRM_Temp=51;95;100 P4Tem_9_Memory_Module_6_VmemGHVRM_Temp=49;95;100 P5Fan_0_Fan_Device_1_FAN1=2000;25300;25400 P5Fan_1_Fan_Device_3_FAN3=2000;25300;25400 P5Fan_2_Fan_Device_5_FAN5=3100;25300;25400 P5Fan_3_Fan_Device_7_FANA=1900;25300;25400 P5Fan_4_Fan_Device_8_FANB=1800;25300;25400
```

I only want CPUx_Temp blocks from the whole output.

Comment: I'd be very tempted to use something like `tr ';' '\n' < datafile | grep 'CPU[0-9]_Temp'`, using `tr` to convert the incredibly long string into a series of lines broken where there were semicolons, and then looking for the detail that is interesting.  Or replace the blanks instead of semicolons.  It would also be a jolly good idea if you showed us the output you want from the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` also:

```
grep -Po 'CPU[0-9]_Temp=[0-9].?'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but is there a way to output the whole block of string instead of discarding beyond the first ";"?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you want) Just play w\ regex. Something like this: ```grep -Po 'P4Tem_[0-9]{2}_Processor_[0-9]_CPU[0-9]_Temp=[0-9]{2};[0-9]{2};[0-9]{2}'```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure grep along will do it. Say 'foo' is a file containing your input line as shown. The code is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"};{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i~/Processor_[0-9]_CPU/) print $i} }' foo |
cut -d_ -f5-9
```

Output:

```
CPU1_Temp=47
CPU2_Temp=55
```

You requested capitalized instances of 'CPU' in proximity to their temps, so I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use `-F';'` instead of `BEGIN{FS=";"}`?

Comment: Kinda works but this is the output I got.  
`85 P4Tem_10_Processor_1_CPU1_Temp=47`
`85 P4Tem_11_Processor_2_CPU2_Temp=54`

Comment: -F makes for more succinct code in some cases. It's just a habit of mine. Regarding "kinda works", I think you may have missed a line break. Ensure that you have the final '| cut -d_ -f5-9' attached to the preceding line. I get output like you report when I break the line before the pipe, '|'.